# log user out and remove session when admin delete the user from admin panel

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using angular 1.6 with nodejs express and using passport js JWT for login and store the token in localstorage and pass it with headers for every request to be sure that the request is from an authorized user.

Now I have admin panel, the admin can delete any user, the issue here that the user might be using the system when the admin deleted him, so how can i check or keep listening that the user is deleted so i clear the local storage and redirect the user.

I know that when user do any action in the system after he is deleted he will not be able since the token is not valid any more, but I want the system to be dynamic listening right away once he is deleted to be kicked out.

My db is mongodb in case it matters.

Thanks!

Comment: When you are sending request to the server with token at that time check for token if token is invalid then return status_code which be informed you as this user is invalid and then redirect user to logib page

Comment: Instead of event handler!

Answer (score 1):

Use socket to emit the event from server when admin delete the account of any logged in user. So as soon as admin remove account the event will emit and it listen to all connected client by this way you can dynamically Clear user local storage.

Hope my answer will help you.